# Belkin F5C350 rackmount surge suppressor audible alarm - why?

Tags: surge-protection

I picked up a used Belkin F5C350 and do not have a manual.  I can not find one online, and Belkin is having trouble finding one.  When I turn on the power switch, and loud piercing alarm sounds, and stays on (a long squeal) until I turn off the device.  The green "breaker" lamp is lit, as is the green "grounded" lamp.  The red "protected" lamp is not lit.  The device is working, as it provides power to all its outlets.

Does anyone know what the alarm indicates, and in turn, how to shut it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the protected light is not lit.  Then it sounds like you need to replace the unit.  Surge protectors are usually good for one hit, then they need to be replaced to properly protect the equipment behind it.